# What is the“Top Five Cards” rule and how does it apply to splitting pots?

Tags: texas-hold-em

I had a problem figuring out the split pot rule the other night, this is the scenario:

I had: 10, 3
My Buddy Had: 10, 5
The Table: K, Q, J, 8, 7

Should the pot be split because we both had the same best five cards? (K, Q, J, 10, 8)

Or did my buddy win because he had a higher kicker?

Comment: yes, kickers _don't count_ when they're the 6th or 7th higher card